# Backbone and cookies / sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, backbone.js, cookies

I have configured jquery to include the cookie header with each request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

On the server-side, I run Node with Express.
Sessions are managed with the express-sessions middleware and the Mongostore plugin.

Before adding the xhrFields configuration, I noticed that for each request, a new session was stored in the database.
I inspected the request headers and noticed that no cookie header was present.

After configuring ajax as above, I notice that still there are too many sessions stored on the server-side.

The problem is the OPTIONS request emitted by Backbone.
I checked the headers of this request and there is no session information included in these requests. Since no Session id is sent to the server, the server creates and stores a new one. It also tries to set a new cookie on the client, which will change the client's session id.

I see two options:

1. Configure ajax somehow to send the cookie info on ALL requests.
2. Disable the session middleware on the option routes (which means I will have to include the middleware on all routes that require the session and NOT include it in all other routes).

I will implement the latter. But maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: the OPTIONS request is a part of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and is designed to negotiate cross domain XHR with the server. since its a meta request, it doesn't contain all information, but the minimum needed to negotiate. it makes more sense for your server to treat the OPTIONS request in a different manner, since no client will ever want to create a session with an OPTIONS call